# Problem to export HTMLElement to excel table / ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, frontend, backend

I'm trying to export a table to excel in my React App, everything is working great with all the functions that returns strings, but I got a  problem with one element, that needs to returns an anchor tag, instead of a string, like in the code below.

Does anyone know a possible solution or an npm package to get the string between the `htmlElement`?

`<a>string</a>`

**Export Functions**

---

```
return fetch(
    `${process.env.API_EXPORTATOR}/api/exporter`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${auth.token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        data,
        headers,
        type,
      }),
    },
  )
```

---

**Element that is returning an empty field in excel:**

```
title: 'SOMETHING',
    ...getColumnSearchProps({
      field: 'SOMETHING',
      onSetFilterToState,
      onList,
      filters,
      placeholder: 'Something',
    }),
    render: data => (data[0]?.type === 'ACTIVE' ? (
      <a
        href={`/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx/${data[0]?.id}/xxxxxxxx`}
        rel="noopener noreferrer"
        target="_blank"
      >
        'YES'
      </a>
    ) : 'NO'),
  },
```

---